# Joomla PHP API check if user is activated in external authentication script

Tags: php, api, authentication, joomla, joomla3.0

I have an external Joomla authenticator script, but it turns out that it ignores if the user didn't activate, and it even ignores if the user is blocked.

I've used the following script with some slight modifications, but the basics are the same:
[Joomla 3 External authentication script](https://gist.github.com/AdamMadrzejewski/020c4fa4b1d0e7af78b8)

Here's my code:

```
...
if ($result)
{
    $match = JUserHelper::verifyPassword($credentials['password'], $result->password, $result->id);
    if ($match === true)
    {
        // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
        $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id);

        //perform the login action
        $error = $app->login($credentials);
        $logged_user = JFactory::getUser();

        if($logged_user->block == 1 && $logged_user->activation) //some kind of check that's not working basically
        {       
            echo $credentials['username'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Invalid password
        die('');
    }
} else {
    // Invalid user
    die('');
}
```

You can see that I tried playing around with the 'block' and 'activation' properties of the user object ([as seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18914703/jaccessgetusersbygroup-how-to-check-is-user-activated-in-joomla-and-sort-it-a)) but it wasn't working properly.

What is the specific property (or properties) that I have to check, to deduct, whether a user that is trying to sign-in via this script is activated or not?

Comment: Block and activation are different. So you have to connect them with `||` like this `if($logged_user->block == 1 || $logged_user->activation)`. Because user might be blocked but active and not active but blocked. non active only means email was not confirmed. Blocked means was explicitly blocked by admin.

Comment: Yes, well the requirement is that blocked users and non-activated users shouldn't be able to access the service. That's why I used the '&&'. But it's not working at all basically, it's like Joomla doesn't even have those properties mapped to the user object.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've posted this to 3 places (even the official Joomla forums) but no answer...

Comment: then you have to use || not && Because you want that if user blocked OR not yet active. With && condition is only for not active same user AND blocked at the same time.